# Simple way To Update Widget TextView Periodically

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, textview

I have a widget with two TextView showing the time and date.

I simply want this batch of code to happen every second:

```
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.rl, pendingIntent);
java.util.Date noteTS = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
String time = "kk:mm";
String date = "dd MMMMM yyyy";

views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTime, DateFormat.format(time, noteTS));
views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvDate, DateFormat.format(date, noteTS));
```

So I need a simple way to update TextView periodically in the widget so the time changes more than the standard 30 mins. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

you may create `Handler` and `Runnable`, and then let the `Handler` to restart your `Runnable` at the specified interval. your program might look like this:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateClockTask);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateCLockTask, 100);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateClockTask);
}

private Runnable mUpdateClockTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        updateClock();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateClockTask, 1000);
    }
};
```

and inside `updateClock()` you do all your UI updates. I suppose all this happens inside the `Activity` with the appropriate `onPause()/onResume()` calls.

Comment: What `Activity`? There is no `Activity` because this is a`Widget`.

Answer (score 1):

u have to use AlarmManager, check this tutorial for details:   http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html#widget_update   dont forget to check this part:

**8. Tutorial: Update widget via a service**

Comment: That's not relevant Their service has nothing to do with periodic updates.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be the use of the [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) classes.
You can use the `Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)` method to accomplish what you need.

Keep in mind that you cannot access the UI thread from within a TimerTask - so the `Handler.postDelayed()` method might be a better bet if you already intend to use a `Handler` with the `Timer` class. There *are* other methods for accessing the UI thread with a `TimerTask`, such as `Activity.runOnUiThread()`.

Comment: i might be wrong, but if you use `TimerTask` you might have troubles updating your UI, because the UI update is supposed to be done on the UI thread, and `TimerTask` runs in its own thread.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You'd have to use `runOnUiThread()` or a `Handler` to update on the UI thread. I would say that usage of the `Timer` method over the `Handler.postDelayed()` method is a matter of preference - at the time of the writing of my answer, the only other proposed answer was the `AlarmManager` method. Certainly, if you plan to use a `Handler` to update on the UI thread anyway, it probably makes more sense to use the `Handler.postDelayed()` method from the start. I'll make an edit to my answer and leave it up as another possible alternative.

Comment: Any chance of an example of where id put this as I've tried this before and failed..

Comment: Where do you put this `Timer` and how do you start it?